# SwiftyJSON and Dynamic Named Objects

Tags: swift, swifty-json

**Problem:** Attempting to consume a JSON payload which contains a dynamic Object name. Since the names of these objects are not sequential or derived from a pattern, I'm unable to travers the payload with SwiftyJSON.  A sample of the dynamic objects looks like this denoted in bold:

**"180A"**: {
  "id": "180A",
  "label": "Oceanside Gate",
  "path": "North",
  "index": "1"
},
**"195C"**: {
  "id": "195C",
  "label": "Dune Beach Gate",
  "path": "North",
  "index": "2"
},
**"211F"**: {
  "id": "211F",
  "label": "Sunset Harbor Gate",
  "path": "North",
  "index": "3"
}

Sample JSON Payload:

```
{
"Direction": {
    "NorthGates": {
        "180A": {
            "id": "180A",
            "label": "Oceanside Gate",
            "path": "North",
            "index": "1"
        },
        "195C": {
            "id": "195C",
            "label": "Dune Beach Gate",
            "path": "North",
            "index": "2"
        },
        "211F": {
            "id": "211F",
            "label": "Sunset Harbor Gate",
            "path": "North",
            "index": "3"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Using SwiftyJSON I'm able to successfully print the label of a known Object, such as "180A":

```
DataManager.getTopAppsDataFromFileWithSuccess { (data) -> Void in

    let json = JSON(data: data)

    if let gateLabel = json["Direction"]["NorthGates"]["180A"]["label"].stringValue {

        //output: "Oceanside Gate"
        println("NSURLSession: \(gateLabel)")
    }
}
```

Since the dynamic object names are not static, I'm unable to use the pre-defined object names in the code above to locate the label value.  The following attempts return nil values:

```
//stringValue = nil
if let gateLabel = json["Direction"]["NorthGates"][0].stringValue {
        println("NSURLSession: \(gateLabel)")
    }

//stringValue = nil
if let gateLabel = json["Direction"]["NorthGates"][0]["label"].stringValue {
       println("NSURLSession: \(gateLabel)")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the solution:**

```
if let gates:[String: JSON] = json["Direction"]["NorthGates"].dictionaryValue {

        for item in gates {
             println("Dynamic Object Gate Name: \(item.0)")    //Gate Name
             println(item.1["label"].stringValue)              //Gate Label
             println(item.1["path"].stringValue)               //Gate Path
             println(item.1["index"].stringValue)              //Gate Index
        }
    }
```